# VisualStudio does not show correct contents of a struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a somewhat strange problem with VisualStudio: when running in debugger, I can halt at specific positions and inspect the data which are used there. So far so good, this worked well until now.

Now I have changed one of my structs (renamed a member, added a new one at the end). The funny situation: when I inspect the related variable in debugger now, it still shows me the old, unchanged contents of the struct, means the old name of the one member and the new one is missing completely! Even when I explicitly set a watch to this new member of the struct, it is telling me it is unknown!

Any ideas how to fix this? As this looks like some strange problem with buffered data I already tried to clean/rebuild everything, but with no success...

Comment: You probably have to rebuild your debugging symbols (.pdb file). Try doing a clean, and then build of your application

Comment: Do you have precompiled headers enabled?  Is the structure definition included in the precompiled header?  Have you rebuild the PCH?

Comment: OK, it was the .pdb-file - amazingly it is NOT deleted on a clean/rebuild :-/

Comment: It does (I just tried just to make sure). Did you check for any warnings about PDB file is use during the rebuild? I've seen that a few times.